# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^{n^p}$ converges for $p>1$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For $p=2$, the ratio test works as follows:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\vert\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}\right\vert=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)^{n^2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1}=e^{-1}<1.$$
Then for $p>2$, the series converges by the comparison test. Moreover, WolframAlpha says the series converges for any $1<p<2$, but ratio test does not make sense for that $p$. Which convergence test could work for $1<p<2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $\ln (1-\frac1  n) \leq -\frac  1 {2n}$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Now compare the given series with $\sum e^{-(1/2)n^{p-1}}$. This last series converges: $e^{-x} \leq \frac  {k!} {x^{k}}$ for any $k$ and we can choose $k$ so that $(p-1)k >1$.